# Blue horizontal lines in VSCode using a Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is anyone else seeing this in VSCode?

I'm using Catalina V 10.15.7.

My graphic are "**AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8 GB
Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB**" if that helps.

[image]

Comment: try disable graphics acceleration

Comment: @rioV8 no luck with that.